# php hashtag system not working properly query is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

i have a hashtag system in which u can write any hashtag and it will convert into a link now i want my hashtag page to show all the images consisting of that hashtag i have a sq query too for that but what that query is doing it is only showing the pix which have # in their description
this is my sql query

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE desccription like '%#$tag%' and ext='';
```

and i am fetching tag from url

```
$filter = $_GET['hashtag'];
$tag = filter_var($filter,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);?>
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), add punctuation and fix spelling and grammar.

Comment: _“but what that query is doing it is only showing the pix which have # in their description”_ – … and? Do you want it to behave differently? Well then tell us, _how_ - or do you think we can read your mind?

Comment: i want the query to fetch the word in $tag & search for #$tag(whatever is in the variable tag) in description of photos from photos table and show all the pics which have $tag in them . @misorude

Comment: `SELECT * FROM photos WHERE desccription like '%#$tag%' and ext='';` isn't valid SQL - or at least it is but it will render '%#$tag%' as a literal string.. unless you're omitting PHP code?

Comment: As @misorude just pointed out on my answer, you have a php variable in an SQL string, but have given no indication how you generated that SQL string. How do you create that SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to substitute the variable `$tag` in a string. You need double quotes for that.

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE desccription like "%#$tag%" and ext=''; //Note. Replaced single quotes with double.
```

Comment: These are “SQL quotes”, you are talking about PHP quotes. (Not saying that the latter don’t need to be replaced probably, but not the ones you are referring to here.)

Comment: @misorude very good points. In fact, the OP hasn't made it clear how he is generating the SQL string. I should ask that.

Comment: @dhruvsunoly that's not an adequate description of your problem. You don't want to make us guess, it wastes time and then people will not be interested in helping. As others have said, please edit your question to make the context of this code clear. Presumably $tag is a variable in PHP. Please show how you are constructing the SQL, by adding some PHP code around it. Also show some sample data you are targeting in the table. N.B. You really ought to be using [parameterised queries](http://bobby-tables.com/php) instead of injecting variables into your SQL like that.

Comment: actually i was using filtervar function and then i was putting that variable in sql query i tried this query with raw variable it worked thanx for takng a look into my problem